# Calling mapreduce from Shiny server

Tags: shiny, rhadoop

I am trying to parallelize my program using RHadoop. I am using shiny server to plot my data after using mapreduce from rmr library.

The mapreduce script works fine in R and I am facing issues while calling the mapreduce script from shinyserver. My problem similar to the one that is given in this link: https://github.com/rstudio/shiny/issues/592